# Confidentiality then Integrity with different keys

Tags: encryption, keys, mac, integrity

Can anyone describe how we can do what is said in the below sentence which is in [Mark Stamp crypto slides (PPTX)](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~stamp/infosec/powerpoint/1_Crypto.pptx) on slide number 101 :

> Can do a little better - about 1.5 “encryptions”

The whole slide is as follow :

> ### Confidentiality and Integrity
>
> - Encrypt with one key, MAC with another key
> - Why not use the same key?
>
>   - Send last encrypted block (MAC) twice?
>   - This cannot add any security!
> - Using different keys to encrypt and compute MAC works, even if keys    are related
>
>   - But, twice as much work as encryption alone
>   - Can do a little better - about 1.5 "encryptions"
> - Confidentiality and integrity with same work as one encryption is a    research topic

Comment: Do you have a link to the specific slides? If so, please edit it into the question.

Comment: The 1.5 "encryptions" is definitely referring [AES-GCM](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/27109/23623). TL;DR: You only encrypt with AES (in CTR mode) and then do one binary finite field multiplication which roughly takes the time of 0.5 AES encryptions. Concerning the last point: [OCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCB_mode) can do this and it's subject to the on-going [CAESAR competition](http://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar.html).